# AngularJS Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token VM1505:3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-material

I am getting this Invalid or Unexpected Token error. I'm using Angular1.5 WITH Angular Material 1.1.0 and AngularFire 2.3.0
[image]

My app.js code is

```
(function() {
angular.module('3etest', ['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons', 'ng-fx', 'ngAnimate'])
       .config(['$routeProvider','$mdThemingProvider', function($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
    .accentPalette('red');
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'assets/views/home.html',
    })
}])
})();
```

Comment: please reprocude your problem with a plunker or jsfidle.

Comment: Is this the only file you have?

Comment: Maybe try using the `unminified` file of `angularjs`? Instead of `angular.min.js`, change it to `angular.js`.

Comment: Using un-minified is not working either